# Place a "Call Us" button that dials the number on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to place a "Call us" button on my website that should dial a number on mobile devices when clicked. Now, I know it can be done via Call us

The problem is that when I open the site with Firefox on desktop, and click the button it gives the error that "tel" isn't associated with any program.

Hence, I want the desktop visitors to redirect to /contact-us/ when clicked on this button

Can anyone suggest I can I toggle b/w mobile and desktop functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a media query to show the "Call us" button only on mobile devices screens. That'd be the most easy way to prevent the problem.

```
.call-us{ display:none; }
@media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
  .call-us {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

You could also toggle the `href` attribute between `tel:XXXXXX` and `/contact-us/` using [modernizr's](http://modernizr.com/) `mq` function:

```
if (Modernizr.mq('only screen and (max-width: 40em)')) {
  $('.call-us').attr("href", 'tel:XXXXXX');
}
```

This is just a desktop-first example, I don't know if it suits your code.

**Why am I doing it desktop-first and not mobile-first?**
Because the contact-us link would always work but the tel one wouldn't. So, in case the toggle fails, the user still gets a nice UX.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the jQuery remove method.

Call btn:

```
<div> <a class="call-btn" href="contact-us.html"> Call Us </a> </div>
```

JQuery on body:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(window).resize(function (){

if ( $(window).width() < 600 ) {

$('a.call-btn).remove();

}
})

</script>
```